# Sitefinity 10, feather API controller and autenthication

Tags: sitefinity, feather

We have set up our platform using sitefinity and MVC (Feather widgets). This works well for the website itself. We now want to develop an app aswell that is going to user REST services.
For this we have implemented 
https://docs.sitefinity.com/implement-the-apicontroller-mvc
If we navigate to the url in the web browser we get the correct results.

I am now making a demo application in WPF to consume this service and test all functions
I am using https://docs.sitefinity.com/request-access-token-for-calling-web-services#resource-owner-client-flow-request-a-token-by-a-trusted-client
this link, but after following the examples I am getting some errors for which I do not know the solution.

I have solved the login issue and I get a valid token. But I now get a 'unsupported media type' error which I can not place.
Does anybody know what might cause this error?

Edit: I started a debug window, and it seems like I am not getting an auterized user on the server side. So I do not know who's data I should show.
I have found http://docs.identityserver.io/en
as documentation, but i did not find any documentation on how to do this in sitefinity correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have some written an example here about getting the authentication token then calling the service to create/get items. This is all JavaScript based.

Have a look at [~/Mvc/scripts/PressReleaseWebService/script.js](https://github.com/jonathanread/SitefinitySamples.PressReleaseWebService/blob/master/Mvc/scripts/PressReleaseWebService/script.js)

https://github.com/jonathanread/SitefinitySamples.PressReleaseWebService

Make sure you are including the Authorization token as part of the Header and it's value is 'Bearer {TOKEN}'.  Also including the x-sf-service-request header is needed.  Check out these [postman](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/tutorial-postman-sample-odata-queries) samples too!  Last place/thing to check would be that the user you are using has the correct permissions to access the data under Administration > Web Services > {YOUR-SERVICE}